# How get path to wallpaper in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, wallpaper

How get path to wallpaper in Linux? (for example Ubuntu)
I wanna get current wallpaper and process with openCV and c++.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and my wallpaper was written to .cache/wallpaper/<file_name>, where file name seems to be some sort of randomly generated ID

Comment: I hope that is some function to get current wallpaper.

Comment: Unfortunately this is dependent on which window manager you use (Unity, Gnome, etc.). So there is no standard location for wallpapers.

Comment: It's certainly going to vary from one linux system to another.  A good project would be to get a VM and a bunch of different linux distro images and see how they all do it.  Then you could be the one that makes a C++ library to get the wallpaper of any Linux  distro.

Comment: Depends on what desktop environment is in use; Unity, KDE, Gnome, Xfce, CDE, xmonad and a ton more all do things their own way. https://www.freedesktop.org tries to standardize things like this, but not all environments follow that, but try digging through that site; maybe yo can find something useful.